# PySMB Handler - [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x, smb

I am tring to use PYSMB smb handler to save files to windows shared folder from Linux box. Currently, I am running the code on windows box to test.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
from smb.SMBHandler import SMBHandler
director = urllib.request.build_opener(SMBHandler)
fh = director.open('smb://username:password!@Directory/path/upload_file.txt')
fh.close()
```

Below is the part of error shown.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smb\SMBHandler.py", line 45, in smb_open
    names = n.queryIPForName(host)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nmb\NetBIOS.py", line 79, in queryIPForName
    ret = self._pollForQueryPacket(trn_id, timeout)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nmb\NetBIOS.py", line 144, in _pollForQueryPacket
    raise ex

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nmb\NetBIOS.py", line 131, in _pollForQueryPacket
    data, _ = self.sock.recvfrom(0xFFFF)

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Though there are many solutions regarding the error, there is nothing specific to smb handler. Can you help me figure out the issue?

Thank you.